# Cannot access Git Organization/repository from AzureDevOps (Build Pipeline)

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have created an organization inside GitHub and moved my personal repo to the organization repo. Then I have added service connection with Git and also did GitHub connection inside azure DevOps. Now I would like to access my organization repo from azure build pipeline but it is not listing my organization repo and it only shows personal accounts repos.

It is saying "This setting is required". But I have added git connection and also service connection.
[image]

Accepting your help and suggestion.

Comment: Please try again in browser incognito mode. Sometime I have similar issues with authenticaton to github or azure and usuall try from incognito mode helped.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej thank you very much for your suggestion. I have tried but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether the selected service connection is to a `GitHub-InstallationToken`. When I choose this type of service connection, I reproduce this problem.

[image][image]

In addition , you can try to create a new service connection authorized with GitHub personal access token to see if this problem still exists.